# WPF global event handler in App.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind

Hi we would to handler the event OnPropertyChanged and gets the value in all application forms of this variable.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows; 
public partial class App : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    #region - Connected -
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Connected status
    /// </summary>
    private Boolean connected = false;
    public Boolean Connected
    {
        get { return connected; }
        set
        {
            if(connected != value)
            {
                connected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Connected");
            }
        }
    }       
    #endregion - Connected -


    #region - INotifyPropertyChanged implementation -
    // Basically, the UI thread subscribes to this event and update the binding if the received Property Name correspond to the Binding Path element
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion - INotifyPropertyChanged implementation - 
}
```

how can fired this event "OnPropertyChanged" and get the value Connected On all App's windows.

Comment: I would not recommend using on property change in this situation, you may want to create custom event and subscribe to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the surface, this looks as simple as each form calling

```
(Application.Current as App).PropertyChanged += ....
```

And in your handler, use

```
(sender as App).Connected
```

to get the value of that property.

Comment: not more complex my situation is like explain in my post.
This works for event , but how can I retrive the value of Connected Property ? e.g.:
'public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {       
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           GridRoot.DataContext = this;
            (Application.Current as App).PropertyChanged += MainWindow_PropertyChanged;}
private void MainWindow_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {Button.Content = "status : " + App.Current.Properties["Connected"];}
}'

Comment: `sender` is the app itself, it's the instance that raised the event. Just do `(sender as App).Connected`